# Url params in laravel integration test

Tags: laravel, parameters, phpunit

I use `$this->get('/users/1', ['access_token' => 'blablabla']);`. Can't see 'access_token'.

But `$this->get('/users/1?access_token=blablabla');` can be right.

How to ?

---

`$this->call('get', '/users/1', ['access_token' => 'blablabla'])` seems to get right params.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source code. It explained :)

```
public function get($uri, array $headers = [])
{
    $server = $this->transformHeadersToServerVars($headers);

    $this->call('GET', $uri, [], [], [], $server);

    return $this;
}
```

I gave up and use route() function to generate uri.